# is there such as thing as a tapered-to-straight adapter for MTB headset?

Tags: headset

I am trying to assemble a bike for someone in my family.  There are a few challenges. The first is my limited experience, the second is her wish-list, which includes using a 27.5" MTB frameset she already has, a limited budget, and a preference to not use a MTB-style suspension fork but a lighter-weight rigid fork.

The headtube expects a  threadless tapered steerer, 1-1/2" to 1-1/8".  With the limited budget, that leaves only a few choices: low-end all-carbon or an alloy steerer with carbon-blades.  I have seen many low-end carbon forks on eBay, Amazon, and Alibaba, but the reviews are sprinkled with comments like "I had to take a dremel to the dropouts". So I would really prefer to get one with an alloy steerer from a "brand name" bike manufacturer. But they all seem to be straight 1-1/8" steerers, not tapered.

Is there such a thing as an adapter for a headset, whose bottom bearing assembly is a 1-1/2" to 1-1/8" adapter, something along the lines of this mockup:

[image: headset adapter]

Comment: Most higher end road bikes use tapered steerers nowadays too, so they shouldn’t be hard to find. They might be out of your budget though.

Comment: Found a CaneCreek 1-1/2 to 1-1/8 tapered headset and an adapter ring that fits over the 1-1/8 steerer, "unreducing" it to 1-1/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, many headsets made for it come with a crown race reducer. Cane Creek, FSA, Nukeproof and several other big names make them so that you can convert a tapered frame to accept a standard straight 1-1/8" fork. Just be sure to take note of what type of bearing/headset your frame uses whether it be external, zero stack or integrated.

You can also likely buy the crown race reducer separately to be used with your choice of headset. A google search for "reducer crown race" will net you the results you are looking for.